# Inference on a cpu takes 100times longer on one system compared to other systems

Tags: deep-learning, cpu, inference

I am running the below code from https://github.com/clovaai/donut on a cpu takes 815.7 sec on a linux based machine with 20cores and the below RAM info:

Cpu spec:

```
$ lscpu
Architecture:            x86_64
  CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
  Address sizes:         46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
  Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                  40
  On-line CPU(s) list:   0-39
Vendor ID:               GenuineIntel
  Model name:            Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2640 v4 @ 2.40GHz
    CPU family:          6
    Model:               79
    Thread(s) per core:  2
    Core(s) per socket:  10
    Socket(s):           2
    Stepping:            1
    CPU max MHz:         3400.0000
    CPU min MHz:         1200.0000
    BogoMIPS:            4800.25
    Flags:               fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi
                          mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon p
                         ebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monito
                         r ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid dca sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic mov
                         be popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_f
                         ault epb cat_l3 cdp_l3 invpcid_single pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexprior
                         ity ept vpid ept_ad fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rtm cqm rdt
                         _a rdseed adx smap intel_pt xsaveopt cqm_llc cqm_occup_llc cqm_mbm_total cqm_mbm_local d
                         therm ida arat pln pts md_clear flush_l1d
Virtualization features:
  Virtualization:        VT-x
Caches (sum of all):
  L1d:                   640 KiB (20 instances)
  L1i:                   640 KiB (20 instances)
  L2:                    5 MiB (20 instances)
  L3:                    50 MiB (2 instances)
NUMA:
  NUMA node(s):          2
  NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32,34,36,38
  NUMA node1 CPU(s):     1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23,25,27,29,31,33,35,37,39
Vulnerabilities:
  Itlb multihit:         KVM: Mitigation: VMX disabled
  L1tf:                  Mitigation; PTE Inversion; VMX conditional cache flushes, SMT vulnerable
  Mds:                   Mitigation; Clear CPU buffers; SMT vulnerable
  Meltdown:              Mitigation; PTI
  Mmio stale data:       Mitigation; Clear CPU buffers; SMT vulnerable
  Retbleed:              Not affected
  Spec store bypass:     Mitigation; Speculative Store Bypass disabled via prctl and seccomp
  Spectre v1:            Mitigation; usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user pointer sanitization
  Spectre v2:            Mitigation; Retpolines, IBPB conditional, IBRS_FW, STIBP conditional, RSB filling, PBRSB
                         -eIBRS Not affected
  Srbds:                 Not affected
  Tsx async abort:       Mitigation; Clear CPU b

uffers; SMT vulnerable
```

memory spec:

```
$ free -h 
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            62Gi       6.4Gi        42Gi       7.0Mi        14Gi        55Gi
Swap:          8.0Gi          0B       8.0Gi
```

While on another system with the below spec, it take 6sec roughly.

Cpu spec:

```
$lscpu
Architecture:           x86_64
  CPU op-mode(s):       32-bit, 64-bit
  Address sizes:        46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
  Byte Order:           Little Endian
CPU(s):                 64
  On-line CPU(s) list:  0-63
Vendor ID:              GenuineIntel
  Model name:           Intel(R) Xeon(R) Silver 4216 CPU @ 2.10GHz
    CPU family:         6
    Model:              85
    Thread(s) per core: 2
    Core(s) per socket: 16
    Socket(s):          2
    Stepping:           7
    CPU max MHz:        3200.0000
    CPU min MHz:        800.0000
    BogoMIPS:           4200.00
    Flags:              fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxs
                        r sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_
                        good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl smx est tm2
                         ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid dca sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes
                         xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault epb cat_l3 cdp_l3 invpcid_single in
                        tel_ppin ssbd mba ibrs ibpb stibp ibrs_enhanced fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms inv
                        pcid cqm mpx rdt_a avx512f avx512dq rdseed adx smap clflushopt clwb intel_pt avx512cd avx512bw a
                        vx512vl xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves cqm_llc cqm_occup_llc cqm_mbm_total cqm_mbm_local dtherm
                        ida arat pln pts pku ospke avx512_vnni md_clear flush_l1d arch_capabilities
Caches (sum of all):
  L1d:                  1 MiB (32 instances)
  L1i:                  1 MiB (32 instances)
  L2:                   32 MiB (32 instances)
  L3:                   44 MiB (2 instances)
NUMA:
  NUMA node(s):         2
  NUMA node0 CPU(s):    0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32,34,36,38,40,42,44,46,48,50,52,54,56,58,60,62
  NUMA node1 CPU(s):    1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23,25,27,29,31,33,35,37,39,41,43,45,47,49,51,53,55,57,59,61,63
Vulnerabilities:
  Itlb multihit:        KVM: Mitigation: VMX unsupported
  L1tf:                 Not affected
  Mds:                  Not affected
  Meltdown:             Not affected
  Mmio stale data:      Mitigation; Clear CPU buffers; SMT vulnerable
  Retbleed:             Mitigation; Enhanced IBRS
  Spec store bypass:    Mitigation; Speculative Store Bypass disabled via prctl and seccomp
  Spectre v1:           Mitigation; usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user pointer sanitization
  Spectre v2:           Mitigation; Enhanced IBRS, IBPB conditional, RSB filling, PBRSB-eIBRS SW sequence
  Srbds:                Not affected
  Tsx async abort:      Mitigation; TSX disabled
```

memory spec:

```
$ free -h 
     total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           125Gi       5.5Gi        51Gi       6.0Mi        68Gi       118Gi
Swap:          8.0Gi       116Mi       7.9Gi
```

Debugging the code shows it gets stuck when running model.inference.
What are the possible problems which cause long inference?

```
from donut import DonutModel
import time
from PIL import Image
import torch
model = DonutModel.from_pretrained("naver-clova-ix/donut-base-finetuned-cord-v2")

model.encoder.to(torch.bfloat16)
model.eval() 
image = Image.open("./donut/misc/sample_image_cord_test_receipt_00004.png").convert("RGB")
t=time.time()
output = model.inference(image=image, prompt="<s_cord-v2>")
print(time.time()-t)
print(output)
```

Comment: Was it using swap space on the machine with less RAM?  Use `vmstat 5` or `dstat 5` and look at pages-in / pages-out per second.  If it's not close to zero, swap thrashing could be why it's very slow.  Otherwise IDK, I'm not familiar the software you're using.  I'm just here for the [cpu] tag.  A 20-core Broadwell Xeon has less FPU throughput than a 32-core Cascade Lake, but not by a large fraction.  The per-core L2 caches on the Cascade Lake are a lot bigger (1MiB vs. 256KiB), and it has AVX-512 which might help some (but not for peak FLOPs since it only has one 512-bit FMA unit.)

Comment: Neither CPU has native hardware support for bfloat, only conversion between standard float16 and float32.  (The F16C extension).  Perhaps there's something helpful in AVX-512BW instead of AVX2 for integer manipulation of BF16 to help converting it to or from float32, if that's what the library is doing.

Comment: Well swap thrashing explains the direct cause of why it was slow on the Broadwell Xeon, but the amount of memory used depend on the software, so I have no idea, sorry.  Just a random guess, perhaps memory use scales with the number of threads?  If the Broadwell machine has less RAM per logical core than your desktop, maybe that's why your desktop managed it.  Or maybe different software versions, or a config setting somewhere.  I wonder if anything the software does depends on CPU features it detects (like AVX-512).  Like I said, I don't know any details about any deep-learning software. :/